# blocking the address / images in laravel

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess

How can I block my url, e.g. `myapp.com/images` on production? By typing this address, the user can check all available images from the server. I can not connect with images while working locally, but I have this problem on production. Thank you for your help

Comment: If you are running Apache, you can drop a `.htaccess` file in your images directory with `Options -Indexes` which should help.

Comment: Thanks for answering, could you write exactly what I should put in .htaccess?

Comment: `Options -Indexes`

Comment: Cool. I added that info in an answer in case someone else finds this looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the file listing by adding the following to your `.htaccess` file (assuming you are running Apache):

```
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use middleware to restrict access to this site. This also provide you an option to give access to a certain users (especially with login accounts)

RestrictionsMiddleware.php

```
...
     public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
         if (Auth::guard('yourguard')->check() || Auth::guard('otherguard')->check() ) {
                    return $next($request);
            }else{
                return redirect('/home');   
            }

    }
```

then if you want to total restriction then just redirect to any landing page you want.

```
            return redirect('/home');
```

You just declare it on the controller or function you want to have this restriction. in my case i declare it to the construct of the controller

MyController.php

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('restriction_middleware');
    }
```